# Packages and NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, nsfilemanager

I was about to post this as a question but I solved it as I was phrasing the problem. Suppose you're using code like in the snippet below...

```
  NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSDirectoryEnumerator *enm;

  enm = [fm enumeratorAtURL:path
            includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey, NSURLIsPackageKey, nil]
            options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants|NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants|NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
            errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error){
                 // TODO: Error needed here?
                 return YES;
               }
         ];
```

How do you descend into folders **but not packages**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow it up with something like this:

```
      for (NSURL *url in enm){
        NSNumber *number;
        NSString *name;

        // Retrieve the directory property
        [url getResourceValue:&number forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil];

        // Retrieve the name
        [url getResourceValue:&name forKey:NSURLNameKey error:nil];

        if ([number boolValue] == NO){
          // It's a file!
        } else {
         // It's a folder!

         // Retrieve the package property. 
         [url getResourceValue:&number forKey:NSURLIsPackageKey error:nil];

          if (![number boolValue]){
            // But not a package!
          }
        }
      }
```

For the above code to work, you have to make sure you pass NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey, and NSURLIsPackageKey to the includingPropertiesForKeys parameter.